# Why this limit does not exist?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{1}{x+y}$$

I know that the limit does not exist because of the graphic $z=f(x,y)$, but I couldn't get the same thing approaching the limit with $y=mx,\ y=x$ or with polar coordinates. I always get $\frac{1}{0}$.

How do I show that the limit does not exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x,y)=\frac{1}{x+y}$, then $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0^+} f(x,x)=+\infty$ and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0-}f(x,x)=-\infty$ thus the limit $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)}f(x,y)$ does not exist.